# block local variables in C++

Tags: c++

Where are the block local variables stored (stack, heap or somewhere else)?

```
int foo() {
  int j;  /*local variable*/
  for(...) {
    int i; /* block local variable*/
  }
}
```

if both `j` and `i` are stored in the stack, how do we differentiate them. Namely, how do we separate the `for` scope from the outer function scope?

Comment: Usually in stack or in registers.

Comment: C++ or Java? They are different languages.

Comment: @YuHao: doesn't actually matter here; scope and stack are two different things here. `i` is not visible outside of `for`, so I wonder what OP actually is asking.

Comment: What do you mean with "block"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe you are wondering whether or not a new stack frame is created for the `for` scope? It is not. The compiler simply keeps track of it and generates machine code that obeys the scoping rules.

Comment: You differentiate them by referring to them as j and i respectively...or am I missing something?

Comment: @Magnus Yes, this is what I was wondering. Thank you, your answer makes sense to me

Comment: @Poldie Could the two variables have the same name?

Answer (score 3):

"Scope" is a language feature, meaning that a variable is only visible and living inside the boundaries of the surrounding code block (here: surrounding `{}`).

"Stack" is a computing architecture feature, which allows for functions to be called, operating on their own set of registers, and then, on returning from these functions, restoring the original state of computing as was saved prior to the function call.

Thus, these two concepts are orthogonal to each other. C++ defines, based on scope, which variables are accessible (or reach the end of their lifetime); the compiler adds stack framing as necessary for function calling.